# How to extract filtered tables from mdb using vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to connect VBA to MDB. When I type the code below, all `drpdwnYear.Value` including ALL or specific year always get similar results. I don't understand why the `Else` can't filter the `drpdwnYear.Value`? Can someone help me with this?

By the way, the Query Extract contains `SELECT [Last Name], [First Name], [Middle Name] FROM [Clients]`.

```
strDBpath = GetFileValue(SetDatabasePath)

If strExtractType = "Stretch" Then
    strQuery = GetFileValue("C:\Clients\resources\QueryExtract.txt")
    If Sheets("Clients").drpdwnYear.Value = "ALL" Then
        If Sheets("Clients").drpdwnYear.Value = "ALL" Then
            strQuery = strQuery & " ORDER BY [Year]"
        Else
            strQuery = strQuery & " WHERE [Year] IN ('" & Sheets("Clients").drpdwnYear.Value & "')"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the outer

```
If Sheets("Clients").drpdwnYear.Value = "ALL" Then
    ...
End If
```

clause. It breaks your logic. If the value is not 'ALL', it will make the code skip the the inner `If ... End If` block.

Comment: Hey Luke! You're right. However, is the query below possible?

strQuery = strQuery & " WHERE [Year] IN ('" & Sheets("Clients").drpdwnYear.Value & "')"

The excel data does not seem to work with the query. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not knowing neither the table structure nor the complete query, I would say that the WHERE clause looks ok. Maybe post the whole SQL statement, if you are still having problems.